# Парсинг даты и времени

Tags: java, java-8

Никак не получается составить шаблон для парсинга даты и времени в таком виде:

```
Thu Oct 05 2017 00:00:00 GMT 0300 (MSK)
```

Пробовал такой вариант:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzZZZ (z)", Locale.US)
```

Но летят ошибки. Как можно исправить?

Comment: ни знаю зачем использовать DateTimeFormatter если есть SimpleDateFormat. вот хорошая статья на этот счет http://www.seostella.com/ru/article/2012/02/05/formatirovanie-daty-v-java.html

Comment: Скажите, а time offset точно в корректной форме? Он обычно идет с плюсом или минусом. Откуда вообще у Вас такой формат приходит? Спрашиваю, поскольку `Thu Oct 05 2017 00:00:00 GMT +0300 (MSK)` парсится вот такой штукой `EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss z [ZZ] (zz)`, но если убрать знак, чего я ни разу не видел, то `[ZZ]` не распарсится.

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski, в таком формате мне приходит из javascript со стороны клиента.

Answer (score 1):

Вот код с использованием SimpleDateFormat и вывод даты как вам надо.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GTM' Z (z)", Locale.US);
Date currentDate = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(currentDate));
```

Выводит **Fri Oct 06 2017 08:43:32 GTM +0600 (ALMT)**

Comment: К сожалению, не решается проблема со знаком смещения. "+" в данном случае не нужен